# Change WiFi hotspot channel on Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge

Tags: samsung, wifi-hotspot

I'm using WiFi hotspot on Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge running Android 7.0. There's a lot of nearby APs broadcasting on channel 1, so I want to change the WiFi channel.

I've tried looking for settings in Settings > Mobile Hotspot and Tethering > Mobile Hotspot > Configure Mobile Hotspot, but there are no available settings to change the WiFi channel.

I found references to a 'Show advanced options' button when I Google this problem, but that button is not present on my phone.

How to change the WiFi hotspot channel on Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge?